# How to override an inline style that is apparently set by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is an image on this page http://www.robertsroofing.com/services-view/leak-repair/ specifically the orange water droplet icon above the photo. I want to hide this (display: none) but can't seem to target via css. So i also tried to add some javascript at the bottom of the page but that doesn't work either. Maybe it's not targeting right but I feel I tried everything.

```
<article id="post-1975" class="post__holder post-1975 services type-services status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
  <figure class="featured-thumbnail thumbnail large"><img src="http://www.robertsroofing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/icon-leak-tile.png" alt="Reliable Commercial Roof Leak Repair" style="display: inline;"></figure>
</article>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.type-services .thumbnail img').attr('style','display: none');
})
</script>
```

I do need to specifically target the parent .type-services class as this template is shared with other content. I just need the image hidden when the .type-services class is used.

Comment: Please include the relevant markup in your question rather than linking to the page - see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You have a typo in your selector.  Not sure if that's your issue.  `thumnail`

Comment: You've used `.thumnail` missing a 'b'

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't the typo. That was just one of the many iterations I had in there.

Comment: Sorry for linking to a page, I just don't know what code is causing the inline style to be applied directly on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element has an inline style of `display: inline;`. This is why your CSS override is not working. Inline styles always take precedence over CSS rules, regardless of how specific your selector is.

[image: inline style]

There are 2 ways you can fix this. 1 is in your CSS, just add `!important` to force override of the style:

```
article.type-services figure.thumbnail > img { display: none !important; }
```

or, if you want to stick with the jquery method, fix your selector to target the correct class - you have a typo in 'thumbnail'. Also, you should use the 'css' function, rather than completely overriding the 'style' attribute.

`$('.type-services .thumbnail img').css('display', 'none');`

or just use the `hide` method

`$('.type-services .thumbnail img').hide();`

Comment: Man, I missed adding important! to the css. Was just looking at it too long, while in a car traveling late last night nonetheless haha. Thank you for fresh eyes on it. I just never new where the inline style was coming from. It was being applied on DOM ready.